# QRadar SIEM AIO v7.3.0 manually added Logsources are showing status N/A

Tags: security, qradar

After QRadar deployment, some of the Log sources were autodiscovered as expected, but others which were not discovered by QRadar automatically, i had added them manually in admin->Log Sources using Bulk option.

All of them are added successfully but they are still showing there Status as N/A. Even the log sources with status N/A are also appearing on Assets tab.

I have also checked that there logs are also appearing in Log Activity tab. Is it a known issue why the status is not showing Success on v7.3.0 even after receiving logs on QRadar?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Log Source İdentifier , Is it Hostname or IP? You should write "Hostname" if There is hostname after time information in the log.Likely you should write IP if there is IP after time information in the log.After that you sould enable/disable log source and wait a few minutes, it should be success.

For example;
Apr 10 17:35:25 127.0.0.1  [Thread-62] com.q1labs.hostcontext.health.Agent: [INFO] ...

You should write 127.0.0.1 on Log source identifier .

I hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing logs from the sources showing as N/A, this is a known issue. If memory serves me this is pretty common for Cisco eStreamer protocol devices.